# Why is the verb "dust" used in opposite forms?

Tags: auto-antonyms

When I **dust** my dresser, I am removing something from the dresser.

When I **dust** a cake, I am adding something to the cake.

How did this happen?  I've heard of words taking different meanings during the transition between British English and American English.  [I understand how *sanction* came to mean multiple things.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/how-did-sanction-come-to-have-two-opposite-meanings)  Some words that are auto-antonyms are clear through context, but consider these:

> I dusted the dresser with my Swiffer.
>
> I dusted the dresser with a bag of <strike>cocaine</strike> confetti.

Comment: It's absolutely normal, in fact ubiquitous, in English that words have many meanings.  There are any number of examples of the type you give; it's so common it's not worth mentioning.

Comment: In case anyway wants to get more confused, *to dust* can also mean *to defeat* or *to kill* as in *turn [the enemy] to dust*, and it can also mean *to leave behind* or *to outrun/outrace* as in *leave [the other person] in the dust [that is kicked up and left behind as you speed away from them]*. Hooray, English!

Comment: Sometimes when we verb nouns, we employ handy prefixes. Sometimes we don't.

Consider the pair "encrypt" and "decrypt" for adding and removing encryption.  One might imagine the pair of verbs "endust" and "dedust".  Ironically, the commercial product "Endust" is intended to dedust things.

Comment: You forget the 3rd usage: When you **dust** a bad guy, you neither add nor remove but change his/its nature -- from (un)living to (eventual) dust/compost.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sure, I mean we could keep going with the slight euphemisms.  When I can **dust** someone while driving by leaving them behind when I speed off.

Comment: related: [Dust vs. Undust?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189755/dust-vs-undust)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Vaguely.  I read this one before I asked the question.  To me, this question wasn't so much about **dust** specifically, as the verbification of nouns which then come to have two opposite meanings.

Comment: Just going to leave this here: https://smile.amazon.com/Amelia-Bedelia-Chapter-Book-Box/dp/0062334204/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468777839&sr=8-1&keywords=amelia+bedelia

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The reason it's even *possible* for ***to dust*** to have two contradictory meanings is simply that there's *no single fixed relationship* between the underlying noun and one particular activity closely associated with it (logically, one might be just as likely to *apply* dust as to *remove* it).

Much the same applies to some other nouns used as verbs...

> **seed** *(seed a lawn = apply lawnseed, seed a tomato = remove the seeds)*
>    **stone** *(stone a heathen = throw stones **at** him, stone a cherry = remove the stone)*
>    **screen** *(screen a movie = present **on** a screen, screen from view = hide **behind** a screen)*
>    etc., etc. <sub>(more examples on [mentalfloss.com](http://mentalfloss.com/article/49834/14-words-are-their-own-opposites))</sub>

Thus, to the extent that there's a *reason* for the dual use, it's because in the real world there are multiple relatively common actions associated with the base noun, and in most cases *context* makes the relevant meaning obvious, so this doesn't cause problems for native speakers.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy: I must be honest. I thought of ***seed*** all by myself, but it was googling ***dust seed verb opposite*** that led me to a page titled *14 Words That Are Their Own Opposites* where I found the others. Bizarrely though, since the relevant search is still there on my browser "Back" mutton, I rechecked and now notice ***25** Words That Are Their Own Opposites* on [the same site](http://mentalfloss.com/article/57032/25-words-are-their-own-oppositeshttp://mentalfloss.com/article/57032/25-words-are-their-own-opposites). I can't quite see how I missed that first time around! :)

Comment: Here's a [freshman linguistics puzzle dealing with verbing nouns](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf). There are a lot of different kinds of verbing, but the puzzle deals with the two mentioned here. The kind that refers to depriving something of something else is called the Privative sense; the kind that refers to providing something with something else is called the Provisional sense.

Comment: @John: Oh, that's very interesting. I never thought it through fully when I was posting the answer, but now you've flagged it up I suppose it's only natural that the two *main* actions one might associate with a "noun turned into verb" would largely be identifiable as "[de]privation" and "provision" (remove or add "noun"). Perhaps such usages aren't as complicated or arbitrary as they seem at first.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just +1'd your comment for '"Back" mutton'.

Comment: @FF: There's also Instrumental (_horsewhip somebody_), Manner (_whipsaw somebody_), Means (_railroad somebody_), and plenty of metaphoric and idiomatic uses that deal with all kinds of relations (_ladder one's stockings, nose someone out for a position, foot the bill_). It's like you said -- the context chooses the interpretation. This is part of what the slogan "Semantics Underspecifies" means.

Comment: @John: Presumably that's part of what makes it so difficult to bring our massively enhanced computing power to bear on the field of linguistics. Especially *semantics*, since most of the "meaning" of most utterances can't really be gleaned from the text itself - it's "out there", in the form of pragmatics & context. You linguists may no longer be ploughing such a *lonely* furrow, but you sure picked a tough and tortuous one!

Comment: @FF: Oh, but we can bring it to bear. There's been a lot of work done on contextual analysis; for instance [FrameNet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/), which was developed by Chuck Fillmore, who dreamed up the concept of conceptual frames and hooked them up with metaphor theory. Framenet and [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) are both available for anybody, having been developed by US government grants. And they're very widely used.

Comment: @John: I suspect it'll be some time before initiatives like that lead to chatbots that never make daft mistakes. A couple of weeks ago I watched a talk on AI (by [Nick Bostrom](http://www.nickbostrom.com/), I think - love that guy!) where pragmatics would imply his example chatbot simultaneously lived in America and the US, *and* was simultaneously a happily-married man and a woman looking for romance. I know that one was just based on statistically likely responses at the *utterance* level, but machine *understanding* of language still seems some way off even for smarter ("true AI") systems.

Comment: Well, there's a certain self-reinforcing regression involved. "True AI" is always on the horizon; if we can already do it, that's not really AI. Whenever AI advances -- by centimeters, like all sciences -- it gets heralded and blown up, and then you never hear about that particular thing again. Meanwhile, downstream, these are making a whole lot of things work better, but it isn't AI, it's "updates". There will always be errors in transcription or translation; there always have been.  Why worry about labels?

Comment: @John: Some labels are good. I really feel I've learned something today by becoming consciously aware of *Privative, Provisional, Instrumental, Manner, Means* as major subtypes within "verbification" (ta muchly! :). And I'd love to imagine that "big data analysis" will soon allow us to autogenerate easily-absorbed summaries of relative prevalence, preferred context, etc. for all those types and more. I'm no "ontologist", but I feel that knowing more about how *language* works could teach all of us more about both what the world *is*, and what it *"means"*.

Comment: Haha, "the ratings board must screen the movie before the cinemas can screen the movie."

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh my gosh why has no one ever told me of FrameNet or WodNet o.0

Answer (score 13):

It happened the same way all language happens: somebody needed a way to say something, and found a way. In this case, different people (well, maybe the same person, but probably different people) needed ways to say "put dust on" and "remove dust" in different contexts, and both used the obvious (in English) method of verbing a noun.

It probably never occurred to either of them that it might be ambiguous, because *in context*, it wasn't. In most contexts, it still isn't.

Comment: `"...the obvious method of verbing a noun."` Ah, using the method while describing the method. Well done.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell the meaning of to *dust* only by the context where it is used. What do you do with Swiffer? You clean the dust. What do you do to a dresser with a bag of confetti? You can't remove dust with it. That's the way English developed over the years with contronyms because you don't need to coin or borrow other verbs as they can never cause any confusion.

There are many [**contronyms**](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/75-contronyms-words-with-contradictory-meanings/) in English as the link indicates. To dust is one of them as it means:

> To add fine particles, or to remove them

The linked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) article calls it *auto-antonym*:

> The terms "autantonym" and "contronym" were coined by Joseph T.
>   Shipley in 1960 and Jack Herring in 1962, respectively. Some pairs of
>   contronyms are true homographs, i.e., distinct words with different
>   etymology which happen to have the same form. For instance cleave
>   "separate" is from Old English clēofan, while cleave "adhere" is from
>   Old English clifian, which was pronounced differently. This is related
>   to false friends, but false friends do not necessarily contradict.

Online Etymology Dictionary explains that "to rid of dust" comes form the noun [dust](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dust&allowed_in_frame=0) which meant:

> Old English dust, from Proto-Germanic *dunstaz (source also of Old
>   High German tunst "storm, breath," German Dunst "mist, vapor," Danish
>   dyst "milldust," Dutch duist), from PIE *dheu- (1) "dust, smoke,
>   vapor" (source also of Sanskrit dhu- "shake," Latin fumus "smoke").

Comment: The real question buried in the OP is, "*How did this happen (for the word **dust** in particular)?*"

Comment: @Jim Does my edit to include "that's the way it is" improve my post?

Comment: Yes, that’s better.

Comment: @Jim How is my answer different from the most upvoted one?

Comment: People likely deem FumbleFingers’s answer as getting to the essence of the issue more clearly and succinctly.

Comment: @Jim Oh, yeah...

Answer (score 2):

The two different connotations   developed in the second half of the 16th century, probably by similarity to its original meaning, "to rise as dust".

***[Dust](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dust) (v.)***

> - ***c. 1200, "to rise as dust;" later "to sprinkle with dust" (1590s) and "to rid of dust" (1560s); from dust (n).***

(Etymonline)