# Term for noun whose verb means to do the opposite

Tags: verbs, nouns, terminology

The word 'dust' is kinda peculiar. The verb form dust means to remove the dust from something, not to add dust to it. Is there a term for this type of word relationship and are there other examples?

Comment: It's not a noun-verb issue, but the logic of shorthand speech. Pitted prunes have pits out, and baby formula is made with no infant ingredients. However, [Amelia Bedelia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Bedelia), too, experienced these challenges and often got stuck.

Comment: Interesting! Skin, fleece, gut, husk, shell, paunch (sort of), louse (obsolete), er... behead (sounds like the opposite of de-head!). I haven't found a name for them.

Comment: You can dust a cake with very finely ground sugar.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So then, context matters?

Comment: The verb _dust_ means to remove dust, just as the verb _skin_ means to remove skin, the verb _milk_ means remove milk, and the verb _core_ means to remove a core. These are called Privative verbs; there are also Provisional verbs, like _roof, fence,_ and _water_, which mean to add these things, instead of removing them like Privative verbs. All of these verbs come from nouns, but there are many different ways to make a verb out of a noun.

Comment: See https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dust.  Also, dusters remove dust but may apply some kind of dust—think of crop dusters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the verb "dust" used in opposite forms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336646/why-is-the-verb-dust-used-in-opposite-forms) We've even got a tag for the linguistic phenomenon involved - [***auto-antonyms***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-antonyms). See also [Dust vs. Undust?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189755/dust-vs-undust)

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks for that.