# What does "Will Lift Sanctions" mean?

Tags: american-english, ambiguity, headline-english

A *Wall Street Journal* headline from May 7, 2019 reads

> Pence to Announce U.S. Will Lift Sanctions on Venezuela Gen. Manuel Cristopher Figuera After He Broke Ranks With Maduro

What does *will lift sanctions* means in this expression? I thought that *lift sanctions* would mean increase sanctions over something. Apparently it's the opposite.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lift

Comment: 'move something from a lower to a higher position' - I don't think it's the meaning here.

Comment: scroll down...it also means "end"..." to end a rule or law:
"The restrictions on water usage have been lifted now that the river levels are normal."..."At last they've lifted the ban on jeans at the club."

Comment: Ok, "Lift" means "to elevante" or "to end".

Comment: By way of explanation: sanctions (or any rules) are metaphorically considered a "burden" on the person affected; when you *lift* the sanctions/rules you remove the burden.

Comment: Lift in this case means to "take off" like you lift the lid covering a box...

Comment: Or like how *lifting a gate* (a horizontal barrier) can describe removing a blockage. Only when the arm of the gate is *down* does it prevent access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is totally reasonable.  *Lift* definitely does have the meaning you're thinking of:

> **lift**
>
> 1 a : to raise from a lower to a higher position : elevate
> b : to raise in rank or condition
> c : to raise in rate or amount

But it also has this other meaning:

> 3  : revoke, rescind
>  // *lift* an embargo

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lift

In the case of "lifting sanctions," this other meaning is employed. How do we know that it's this latter meaning and not the former? Only because "lifting sanctions" is a common phrase and it always has this meaning.

---

Also note, in case this wasn't annoying enough, that *sanction* can have essentially opposite meanings:

[How did 'sanction' come to have two opposite meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/how-did-sanction-come-to-have-two-opposite-meanings)